# What is the substitute for is_ref__gc in php7

Tags: php-internals, php-7

In php5, zval struct has a member 'is_ref__gc'. We can use it as follow:

```
zval *x
...
...
if (!x->is_ref__gc)
   {
       printf("newx or newy isn't by ref");
       return;
   }
```

However, in php7, zval doesn't have such a member.
What is the substitute for is_ref__gc in php7?  i.e. how does I modify the above code?

Comment: `Z_ISREF_P`. Like you ought have been doing in PHP 5 as well. There's a reason it's called `is_ref__gc`, you know.

Comment: zvals in PHP 7 aren't usually passed around as pointers, and contain no reference counting by themselves. Read this: https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading

Answer (score -2):

I change

```
if (!x->is_ref__gc)
```

to

```
if (x->value.ref->gc.refcount == 0)
```

Now, it seems to be effective.